# How do I build scikit learn on windows?

Tags: python, python-2.7, scikit-learn

When i run the script : python setup.py install from cmd i get the following error message :

ImportError: No module named sklearn._build_utils

After installing:

- Python 2.7.2 64 bit for windows
- Enthought Canopy which has sciPy,NumPy and matplotlib
- setuptools
- scikit-learn-0.13.1.win32-py2.7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you install from a binary distribution you should not try to build from source. Just reinstall the binary packages for scikit-learn and you should be able to `import sklearn` from your python shell.

Beware, if you use the Python installer from Canopy you should probably better use canopy to install scikit-learn as well: https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/package-index/ (although the current version available on canopy is a bit old: 0.11 instead of 0.13.1).

If you want to install scikit-learn for your own install of [Pythonn 2.7](http://python.org/download/releases/2.7.5/) from the [binary packages repository Christoph Gohlke](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs) you should also install all the dependencies from the same repository (the scipy-stack meta package should provide them all at once).

When ever in doubt you can check which python you a running with:

```
>>> import sys; print(sys.executable)
```

to see the folder where python is installed. You can also list the folders that python uses to lookup packages in:

```
>>> print(sys.path)
```

For scikit-learn or numpy you can do:

```
>>> import sklearn; print(sklearn.__version__); print(sklearn.__path__)
```

and:

```
>>> import numpy; print(numpy.__version__); print(numpy.__path__)
```

**Edit**: now if you really want to build scikit-learn from source (for instance to install the development branch from the github repository, then you should:

- uninstall any previous version of scikit-learn installed with a binary package
- install a C compiler (either from visual studio or mingw)
- follow the instructions from: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/advanced_installation.html#building-on-windows

**Edit 2** fix a typo: replaced `sys.__path__` by `sys.executable`.

Comment: I tried to build scikit-learn from source in the development branch. But when building I get the following error. I even installed all dependancies. 

c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: build\temp
.win32-2.7\Release\sklearn\ensemble\_gradient_boosting.o: bad reloc address 0x0
in section `.data'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: error: Command "g++ -shared build\temp.win32-.7\Release\sklearn\ensemble\_gradient_boosting.o -LC:\Python27\libs -LC:\Python27\PCbuild -Lbuild\temp.win32-2.7 -
lpython27 -lmsvcr90 -o build\lib.win32-2.7\sklearn\ensemble\_gradient_boosting.p
yd" failed with exit status 1....                                      What should I do?

Comment: hi @maheshakya, were you able to successfully build from the source on windows? how did you deal with the error?

Comment: import sys; print(sys.__path__) doesn't work for me, but print(sys.path) works (python 2.7x)

Comment: Indeed, this is a typo. I meant `sys.executable` instead.